# Array grouping to form a new data structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am looking for a possible way to transform my array of object to get this value below. The array i have currently and want to transform is the one titled **currentData** and the required output is the one with title of **output**

**OUTPUT**

```
[  
{
    title: "Main dishes",
    data: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"]
  },
  {
    title: "Sides",
    data: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps"]
  },
  {
    title: "Drinks",
    data: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer"]
  },
  {
    title: "Desserts",
    data: ["Cheese Cake", "Ice Cream"]
  }
];
```

**CURRENT_DATA**

```
[
{"__typename": "ProductsSold", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T17:52:19.369Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 4", "quantity": 2, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 4400000, "unitPrice": 2200000}, 
{"__typename": "ProductsSold", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T20:55:23.637Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 4", "quantity": 3, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 6600000, "unitPrice": 2200000}, 
{"__typename": "ProductsSold", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T20:56:24.879Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 4", "quantity": 3, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 6600000, "unitPrice": 2200000}
]
```

*****Please i need response*****

Comment: What field of CURRENT_DATA should be the `title` and what do you want inside `data` array?

Comment: I want to use  **createdAt** as the title and then **data** should be array of objects with **productName**, **unitPrice** and **Total**

Comment: I tried to make a solution according to your comment. If is not what you want to achieve, add a comment on answer and I will fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

hi this could be done using below logic in `JavaScript`,

within `forEach` method for the array of `currentData` I have checked whether the `currentData.__typename` is already pushed to the `requiredData` array using the findIndex, and if so I am pushing the `currentData.productName` value to the `requiredData.data` array of that index

```
var currentData = [
    { "__typename": "ProductsSold", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T17:52:19.369Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 4", "quantity": 2, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 4400000, "unitPrice": 2200000 },
    { "__typename": "ProductsSold", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T20:55:23.637Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 4", "quantity": 3, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 6600000, "unitPrice": 2200000 },
    { "__typename": "ProductsSold", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T20:56:24.879Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 4", "quantity": 3, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 6600000, "unitPrice": 2200000 },
    { "__typename": "ProductsBuy", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T20:56:24.879Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 3", "quantity": 3, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 6600000, "unitPrice": 2200000 },
    { "__typename": "ProductsBuy", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T20:56:24.879Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 2", "quantity": 3, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 6600000, "unitPrice": 2200000 },
];

var requiredData = [];

currentData.forEach(i=>{
    if(requiredData.findIndex(item=>item.title==i.__typename) > -1){
        var id = requiredData.findIndex(item=>item.title==i.__typename);
        requiredData[id].data.push(i.productName)
    }
    else{
        requiredData.push({
            title:i.__typename,
            data:[i.productName],
        })
    }

})
```

below is the output of the above logic:

```
requiredData = [ { title: 'ProductsSold', 
    data: [ 'Rover 4', 'Rover 4', 'Rover 4' ] }, 
  { title: 'ProductsBuy', data: [ 'Rover 3', 'Rover 2' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could use a `map` function to create an array of elements with `createdAt` as `title`, and `productName`, `unitPrice` and `totalPrice` as attributes of an object to put inside `data` array like this:

```js
let input = [
{"__typename": "ProductsSold", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T17:52:19.369Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 4", "quantity": 2, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 4400000, "unitPrice": 2200000}, 
{"__typename": "ProductsSold", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T20:55:23.637Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 4", "quantity": 3, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 6600000, "unitPrice": 2200000}, 
{"__typename": "ProductsSold", "createdAt": "2020-07-11T20:56:24.879Z", "operationType": "Sell", "productName": "Rover 4", "quantity": 3, "storeId": "5f09f950f6b21a2b5c2d4c3c", "totalPrice": 6600000, "unitPrice": 2200000}
]

let result = [];

result = input.map((el) => {
    return {title: el.createdAt, data: [{productName: el.productName, unitPrice: el.unitPrice, totalPrice: el.totalPrice}]}; 
})

console.log(result)
```